# ClassNotFoundException: SanitizerLogWrapper while starting WebSphere Application server with Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, websphere-8

I've deployed Liferay 6.1 on WAS 8.5.5. While trying to start the server via Eclipse Juno, I'm getting a `ClassNotFoundException` which points to `com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.SanitizerLogWrapper`. Does someone know what the cause might be?

Here are the logs:

```
[8/6/15 9:09:39:152 EDT] 0000005a webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                             java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.SanitizerLogWrapper
at com.liferay.portal.util.InitUtil.init(InitUtil.java:115)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:169)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1678)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1175)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:774)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2182)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.SanitizerLogWrapper
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:599)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:204)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:743)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:720)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:119)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:584)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:584)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing portal-kernel.jar or portal-service.jar

[More here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadportalkerneljar.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Erwan. I have the following jars in lib-->ext folder of my application server: hsql.jar, portal-service.jar, portlet.jar. Do I need to place these files someplace else?

Comment: Declare the class yourselft and see if eclipse ask you to import package. You see if you have it or not. Or on eclispe go on YourProject-->Java Resources-->Libraries-->Web App Libraries-->portal-service.jar-->com.liferay.portal.kernel.log     but according to the package name i think you miss portal-kernel.jar

Answer (score 0):

Liferay requires some classes on the global classpath. You can download them as so called "dependencies". Among them is portal-service.jar

If you deployed Liferay according to the [Administration Guide for Websphere 8.5](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/6-2/installing-liferay-on-websphere-8-5), everything should run (I'm linking the 6.2 version of the docs, but I expect no big changes. If you're on CE, you should update anyways, because 6.1 CE is discontinued for quite a while now)

Comment: Thanks you for your reply Olaf. Where/how do i place this file on the global classpath? What is the global classpath?

Comment: I've linked the installation instructions for your exact version of Websphere AS. Did you read them? Tried them? The documentation explains it as well, better than a stackoverflow answer can.

Comment: Yes, my company (which i'm new to) has the same guide in its documents, and i followed it.